# How can I find differences between several columns

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(37L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 
11L, 12L), X2 = c(40L, NA, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 
NA, 25L, 24L), X3 = c(60L, 44L, 49L, 41L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 
NA, NA, 22L), T1 = c(19L, 55L, 47L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 25L, NA, 33L, 
42L, 50L, 22L), T2 = c(75L, NA, 32L, 44L, 27L, 31L, 17L, NA, 
18L, 45L, 10L, 11L), T3 = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA, 
46L, 36L, 42L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I want to be able to obtain the following info

```
Number_of_values_X1-X3  11
Number_of_missing_in_X1 1
Number_of_missing_in_X2 2
Number_of_missing_in_X3 5
Number_of_missing_in_X1X2X3 1
Number_of_Missing_in_X1_X2  0
Number_of_missing_in_X1_X3  0
Number_of_missing_in_X2_X3  0
```

The same for the three other columns

```
Number_of_values _T1-T3 11
Number_of_missing_in_T1 1
Number_of_missing_in_T2 2
Number_of_missing_in_T3 2
Number_of_missing_in_X1X2X3 1
Number_of_Missing_in_X1_X2  0
Number_of_missing_in_X1_X3  0
Number_of_missing_in_X2_X3  0
```

I tried to do this with the following function but when it is more columns involved, I cannot figure out how to amend this

```
myData <- function(Ecol) {
  N_V <- length(setdiff(df[[column]], NA))
  N_Missing <- sum(is.na(df[[column]]))
  print(paste("Number of values in", column, N_V))
  print(paste("Number of missing in", column, N_Missing))
}
```

Comment: apply to all columns? something like `lapply(df, myData)` FYI, your function does not return anything...It just prints stuff

Comment: @Sotos I gave the desired output, I want it on all columns and all combination columns . The function I wrote is not complete that is why I asked a question, if you could help me with a better solution, I would appreciate it

Comment: Yeah, I see your desired output. I am giving you a hint to try

Comment: Please give an example of your output the way you want it structured and to fit your example.

Comment: What do you mean by *Number of values  X1-X3*? The number of unique values in those 3 columns?

Comment: @Sotos I made the structure of the desired output more clear above

Comment: @Rui Barradas means number of missing values that on the same row for both in X1 column and X3 column

Comment: My results are not the same as yours. In columns `X1` and `X3` there is only 1 `NA`. And the same for the combinations `X1,X2,X3`, `X1,X2`, `X2, X3`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give the total number of `NA` values per column and the number of `NA` values per row of the selected columns.
First define a function and compute a logical matrix.

```
na_cols <- function(X, cols){
  all_na <- apply(X[, cols], 1, function(y) Reduce('&', y))
  sum(all_na)
}

na <- sapply(df, is.na)
```

Now the total number of `NA` values per column.

```
apply(na[, 1:3], 2, sum)
#X1 X2 X3 
# 1  2  5
```

And the number of `NA` values per combination of columns.

```
na_cols(na, 1:3)
#[1] 1

na_cols(na, 1:2)
#[1] 1

na_cols(na, c(1, 3))
#[1] 1

na_cols(na, 2:3)
#[1] 1
```

For columns starting with `T`, the equivalent code is

```
apply(na[, 4:6], 2, sum)
na_cols(na, 4:6)
na_cols(na, 4:5)
na_cols(na, c(4, 6))
na_cols(na, 5:6)
```

Comment: 1:3 is correct that has 1 but 1 and 3 only has 0 , can you please check ? it means if it is 1,2,3 already count as being empty, then we don't use that  unless it is only NA for 1 and 3 on the same row , do it make ny sense ?

Comment: @Learner The 10th row of `df` as you posted it has 3 `NA` in the first 3 columns, including 1,3, and 2,3.

Comment: Yes , it is counted already as being NA for 1 and 2 and 3. I basically want to compare the group 1 which is X1, X2, X3 with the second group T1 to T3 .